# {AMAZON ALEXA} I wanted to know if I want there to be a certain result for an empty slot, how I could phrase an if statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have a program that uses AMAZON.date to get the date, and give the school events on the date. However, if the date slot is empty, I want the date to just default to today. I do not know how to write that the slot is empty. I have tried using this:

```
if (intentRequest.intent.slots.date.value === null){
 currentDateSlot === today; 
 }
```

but it didn't work. I am using JavaScript for this project.

Thank You for any help I get!

Answer (score 0):

If alexa did not capture the date slot from the user, the request to your code will not be having the date object under intentRequest.intent.slots. So you should be checking for the absence of the date object,

```
if (!intentRequest.intent.slots.date) {
    currentDateSlot = today;
}
```

Also you are not setting the currentDateSlot correctly in your code.

Comment: I attempted to do that, and the JSON input did not receive a date. I will give you the link to the updated code. Thank you for helping me! https://pastebin.com/BQhzpUAC